# exit(), return make post data gone

Tags: php, forms, exit

My code looks like this:

```
if(!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    message("Invalid Mail!", "error"); return;

}
```

*message is a function to pop-out an alert.*

However, the entire form will be "emptied" as soon as the error pops out (due to "return"). I'm kind of new, so how do I prevent that?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web servers are usually *stateless*. When your script finishes executing it will forget everything about the request, including submitted form data.

Two common methods in PHP to *save state* are using [session variables](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) (storing user information on the server between requests), or outputting data into hidden form fields for resubmission on the next request (storing information on the client-side between requests). Both are temporary.

A very simple session variable which remembers if you've visited before:

```
<?php

// Tell PHP to use sessions
session_start();

// If the variable is not set
if (!isset($_SESSION['returning_user'])) {
    // They are a new user
    echo 'Welcome first-timer!';
    $_SESSION['returning_user'] = true;

// Otherwise the variable is set
} else {
    // They are a returning user
    echo 'Hello again :)';
}
```

If the user made a mistake when filling out a form, or failed validation, etc, the recommended method is to output the data again in form fields for the user to make corrections, and re-submit it when they are ready.

If you are making a multi-step form wizard, you could "capture" the data from previous steps in a session variable for processing at the end. This is because you will have validated user input on submission - sending it back to the client for storage could be untrustworthy - keeping it on the server is safe.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I've started doing it that way, however, thought that there was a more 'professional' way.

Comment: @Jan AFAIK this is the recommended method. There are some excellent open source form classes available which have done most of the hard work, including multi-step forms, form validation, AJAX forms, embedded forms... and PHP frameworks take it a step further for simplicity and security. IMO don't aim for professional code this early, get it working and find the bugs :) Understand the process. Then re-use others' code for rapid development, as you know what the code will be doing for you behind the scenes

Comment: It seemed a little too easy to me. See, the world's not being that complicated. Thanks!